# The meaning of 'bunched in ripples'

Tags: phrase-meaning

> We found ourselves in a thick white metal cage that opened into the
>   Medical Records room—an empty, warehouse-sized room with no staff, no
>   patients, no chairs, no visitors, and no medical records. Its windows
>   were bolted shut and covered with wire and dirt, **its gray carpet
>   bunched in ripples** from decades of foot traffic. A waist-high
>   cinder-block wall ran the length of the room, separating the waiting
>   area from the area marked AUTHORIZED PERSONNEL ONLY, where several
>   rows of tall metal shelves stood empty.

— *The Immortal Life of Henrietta Lacks* by Rebecca Skloot

Does this mean the carpet is folded in a wavy shape? I can't visualize it.

Comment: [it's when carpet becomes like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=carpet+ripples&tbm=isch)

Comment: @Kreiri... Thank you. I've got it. Do you mind posting an short answer so I can close up my question.

Comment: As @Kreiri +1 has shown, it's due to the carpet stretching from extensive use.